# Hosts files keps reverting when I turn off my computer.

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, hosts-file

I have changed my host file to allow me access via RDC to computers over VPN network. 
I change the ip's and it works fine. My problem is that every time I log back onto my computer they have reverted/deleted. Im using a mac. I am the administrator as well.

im using

```
 sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

To edit my host file.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried to change /etc/hosts instead?

Comment: Im not too sure what yo mean?

Comment: On Mac OS X both files are the **same file** (hard link). `/etc/hosts` and `/private/etc/hosts` have the same inode number (check with `ls -i /private/etc/hosts /etc/hosts`)

Comment: @Matteo 'Will$ ls -i /private/etc/hosts /etc/hosts

,6082256 /etc/hosts 
,6082256 /private/etc/hosts'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cisco's AnyConnect it rewrites the hosts file.

Check if you have a `/etc/hosts.ac` file: AnyConnect uses it to recreate `/etc/hosts`.

In any case you can define aliases with `dscl` (from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111011050950471):

> Instead of modifying the hosts file, it's much more reliable to use the dscl command, which has been available since Leopard. Check out http://jonathan.tron.name/2008/01/05/hosts-aliases-in-leopard

Comment: I checked the '/etc/hosts.ac' There was no content. I put my IP's in there but it still changed back when I rebooted

Comment: My client is having me use Pulse Secure, and I too noticed that my hosts edits were removed on a daily basis. To get my change to persist I disconnected my VPN and made the change. Seems like they make a backup when you connect and overwrite the file when you disconnect.